# Retry to fetch on GraphQLError

Tags: graphql, apollo

Hello folks I came across on graphql errors and I would like to know if there is a way to handle the error by showing an alert to retry refetching the query.

so in a short example I have the following

```
renderError() {
  Alert.alert(
    'ERROR',
    'There is a problem!',
    [
      { text: 'Try again', onPress: () => console.log('refetch query') },
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        onPress: () => console.log('Cancel'),
        style: 'cancel',
      },
    ],
    { cancelable: false },
  );
}

render() {
  if(loading){
    return <Loader loadVisible={loadingVisible} animationType="fade" />;
  } else if (error){
    return <View>{this.renderError()}</View>;
  } else {
    ... 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation in [Apollo Queries](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries#refetching) you can access a `refetch()` function from the render prop pattern.

The same way you have `loading`, `error` and `data` you can use `refetch` and then you just have to pass it and call it in the event you need.

Something like:

```
renderError(refetch) {
  Alert.alert(
    'ERROR',
    'There is a problem!',
    [
      { text: 'Try again', onPress: () => refetch() },
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        onPress: () => console.log('Cancel'),
        style: 'cancel',
      },
    ],
    { cancelable: false },
  );
}

render() {
  if(loading){
    return <Loader loadVisible={loadingVisible} animationType="fade" />;
  } else if (error){
    return <View>{this.renderError(refetch)}</View>;
  } else {
    ... 
  }
}
```